# Why do I have to cast a bit(1) as unsigned in a mysql subquery?

Tags: mysql, casting, bit

For some reason I have to explicitly cast a BIT(1) MySQL column as UNSIGNED in order to get back a 0 or 1 IF I include that column as part of a subquery but not as a "normal" query. Allow me to elaborate...

I have two database tables: contests and votes

```
CONTESTS - id, ..., ...
VOTES - ..., over BIT(1), ..., ...
```

If I run this query I get results I would expect...

```
SELECT votes.over as vote_over FROM votes WHERE votes.contest_id = 38;
```

Result:

```
vote_over: 1    (ok, this makes sense)
```

If, however, I try to select votes.over as a subquery, I get a curious result...

```
SELECT contests.id as contest_id,
    (SELECT over FROM votes WHERE votes.contest_id = contests.id) as vote_over
FROM contests
where contests.id = 38;
```

Result:

```
contest_id: 38
vote_over: 49    (WHAT?)
```

Why is vote_over (a bit column) 49 if it's a subquery, but 1 if it's included in the vanilla query above??! And what is the significance of 49? Why not 2377? 49 is 110001 and this problem would make a little more sense if I had defined the 'over' column as a bit(6) type, but it's a bit(1). This makes no sense!

After some futzing around, I happened upon this query that gave me what I wanted...

```
SELECT `contests`.id as contest_id,
    (SELECT cast(`votes`.over as unsigned) FROM (`votes`) WHERE votes.contest_id = contests.id)
FROM (`contests`) as vote_over
where contests.id = 38;
```

Result:

```
contest_id: 38
vote_over: 1
```

So while I've found a way to get what I wanted out of the query, I don't understand why casting the vote_over result as unsigned makes a difference ONLY in a subquery.

Additional info: I'm running these queries on a MySQL 5.6.14 instance on my laptop. Obviously these queries are just hypotheticals to illustrate the problem I've isolated. They don't make much sense by themselves and I typed them up in the course of debugging a much larger query where that subquery is necessary.

It seems like there's something fundamental that I don't understand about signing bits in subqueries that this problem is exposing. Please help!

Comment: well it seems like the bit is getting converted to something else when you select it. this is probably because you have an int comparison in the where to the subquery... so you have to cast it.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: this is a helpful link as well... it may be that mysql is returning the maximum value allowed for that datatype. http://www.geeksengine.com/database/design/data-type-constraint.php

Comment: @JohnRuddell, tip #6 in that geeksengine link recommends an enum type for a true/false field which I guess is a way around my particular problem, but it seems like a bit(1) *should* only have two possible values. It also seems weird that a result column would be miscast based on an unrelated comparison in a WHERE clause. And why would it only get miscast as part of a subquery and not as a standalone query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `SELECT [bit_column]` is not supposed to return a printable result set in the first place. You are just lucky that it sometimes returns something intelligible.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-field-literals.html:

> **Bit values are returned as binary values**. To display them in printable form, add 0 or use a conversion function such as BIN().

On my box, `SELECT [bit_column]` always returns non-printable characters.

Comment: Thanks! For future reference, what is the recommended method for storing a simple true/false boolean in MySQL? An enum field?

Comment: The built-in `BOOL` (or `BOOLEAN`) type is a [synonym for TINYINT(1)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html). There even are the `TRUE` and `FALSE` constants.