# Why am I getting different results on a subquery and query?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have the following table '`client_ticket_thread`':

```
create table client_ticket_thread
(
    id                bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    client            bigint unsigned                       not null,
    category          varchar(255) collate utf8mb4_bin      not null,
    subject           varchar(512) collate utf8mb4_bin      not null,
    message_count     int unsigned default 0                not null,
    client_read       bit          default b'1'             not null,
    closed            bit          default b'0'             not null,
    time_created      int unsigned default unix_timestamp() not null,
    time_last_message int unsigned default 0                not null,
    time_closed       int unsigned default 0                not null,
    constraint client_ticket_thread_client_credential_id_fk
        foreign key (client) references client_credential (id)
);
```

One of the entries in this table is as follows:

```
7,1,General Inquiry,Thread X,1,true,false,1641790706,1641790707,0
```

I am trying to write a query for a specific purpose and I will need external data from other tables as a result, so in a subquery, I am trying to retrieve the `closed` field with the following statement:

```
select (select ctt.closed from client_ticket_thread ctt where ctt.id=7 and ctt.client=1 limit 1) as thread_active;
```

But the result returns `true`.

However, the following statement returns `false`, as expected.

```
select closed as thread_active from client_ticket_thread where id=7 and client=1 limit 1;
```

When I try retrieving a different field, e.g. `subject`, I get the correct results. What might be causing this error?

Note: I am using MariaDB `10.7.1`.

Comment: You use `limit 1` in the subquery; which implies that there are more than one row for the criteria. If there are other rows your query does not have anything to identify which row is to be returned when the query is used at different times, in different contexts. Could this be a reason? Can you check the data for other rows with the same where condition (without `LIMIT 1`)

Comment: @userMT There is only one row with this criteria as `id` is auto incremented and should be unique. The `limit 1` comes from pure habit. Removing it does not change anything, and as I mentioned, another field can be retrieved as expected.

Comment: Casting (`... select CAST(ctt.closed as integer) ...`) seems to be fixing the problem, still leaving me wondering why it didn't work without casting...

Comment: yes, it seems to have something to do with how MariaDB handles bit values in subqueries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973746/why-do-i-have-to-cast-a-bit1-as-unsigned-in-a-mysql-subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're using a bit field. Since this appears to be a flag, I recommend you change it to boolean. When using a boolean it returns 0/false as expected in each case.

Here is a [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=0e6013ecd6c36c1ea3f6cae449b17ccb) showing what I mean.

```
create table client_ticket_thread
(
    id                bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    client            bigint unsigned                       not null,
    category          varchar(255) collate utf8mb4_bin      not null,
    subject           varchar(512) collate utf8mb4_bin      not null,
    message_count     int unsigned default 0                not null,
    client_read       bit          default b'1'             not null,
    closed            bit          default b'0'             not null,
    client_read_bool boolean default true not null,
    closed_bool boolean default false not null,
    time_created      int unsigned default unix_timestamp() not null,
    time_last_message int unsigned default 0                not null,
    time_closed       int unsigned default 0                not null
);

insert into client_ticket_thread
values
(7,1,'General Inquiry','Thread X',1,1,0,true,false,1641790706,1641790707,0)

select (
select closed_bool
from client_ticket_thread ctt 
where ctt.id=7 
and ctt.client=1 
) as thread_active;
```

What I was finding was that the bit field was in fact returning a value of 48 from the sub query, which I suppose was translated to 'true' in your case, and 0 without the sub query. I don't know why it was returning 48.

I read through the documentation for the bit data type [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/bit/).

> Bits are returned as binary, so to display them, either add 0, or use
> a function such as HEX, OCT or BIN to convert them.

So you can either use boolean in the first place, or `SELECT (SELECT closed+0 FROM ...`